# Android binary xml file error inflating class / cannot make calls to a recycled instance

Tags: java, android

This crashes an Android app running Android 5 Lollipop, but works fine on Android version 4.  It's using the AndroidBootstrap library from [here](https://github.com/Bearded-Hen/Android-Bootstrap).

The relevant code is:

```
public class PreShareFragment extends Fragment
{

private Handler handler;
private BootstrapButton next_button;
private View placeholder;
LayoutInflater root_inflater;
Context context;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    final View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.preshare_fragment, container, false);
    root_inflater = inflater;
    root_container = container;
    phone_number_field = (BootstrapEditText) rootView.findViewById(R.id.phone_number);
    next_button = (BootstrapButton) rootView.findViewById(R.id.preshare_next);

    next_button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
    {
        public void onClick(View v)
        {
            ...
        }
    });

    return rootView;
}
```

My layout XML is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:bootstrapbutton="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
>

<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:id="@+id/pager"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    />

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:id="@+id/placeholder"
    android:background="@android:color/transparent">
    </LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:weightSum="100"
    >

        <Space
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="96">
            </Space>

        <com.viewpagerindicator.CirclePageIndicator
            android:id="@+id/indicator"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|bottom"
            style="@style/StyledIndicators"
            />

        <com.beardedhen.androidbootstrap.BootstrapEditText
            android:id="@+id/phone_number"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:hint="Your mobile phone number"
            android:textColor="@color/black"
            android:textCursorDrawable="@null"
            bootstrapbutton:be_roundedCorners="true"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|bottom"
            bootstrapbutton:be_state="success"
            android:inputType="phone"
            android:imeOptions="actionDone"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
            />

        <com.beardedhen.androidbootstrap.BootstrapButton
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Next Step"
            android:id="@+id/preshare_next"
            bootstrapbutton:bb_type="success"
            bootstrapbutton:bb_roundedCorners="true"
            bootstrapbutton:bb_icon_right="fa-chevron-right"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|bottom"
            />

</LinearLayout>
```

the stack trace is:

```
12-07 22:44:41.453  24674-24674/com.app E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.app, PID: 24674
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.app/com.app.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #62: Error inflating class com.beardedhen.androidbootstrap.BootstrapButton
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2298)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2360)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:144)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1278)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)
 Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #62: Error inflating class com.beardedhen.androidbootstrap.BootstrapButton
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:633)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:743)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:806)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:809)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:504)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:414)
        at com.app.view.PreShareFragment.onCreateView(PreShareFragment.java:81)
        at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:1504)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:942)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1121)
        at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:682)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1484)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onStart(FragmentActivity.java:571)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnStart(Instrumentation.java:1220)
        at android.app.Activity.performStart(Activity.java:5949)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2261)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2360)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:144)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1278)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)
 Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:288)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:607)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:743)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:806)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:809)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:504)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:414)
        at com.app.view.PreShareFragment.onCreateView(PreShareFragment.java:81)
        at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:1504)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:942)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1121)
        at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:682)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1484)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onStart(FragmentActivity.java:571)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnStart(Instrumentation.java:1220)
        at android.app.Activity.performStart(Activity.java:5949)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2261)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2360)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:144)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1278)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)
 Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Cannot make calls to a recycled instance!
        at android.content.res.TypedArray.getString(TypedArray.java:167)
        at com.beardedhen.androidbootstrap.BootstrapButton.initialise(BootstrapButton.java:182)
        at com.beardedhen.androidbootstrap.BootstrapButton.<init>(BootstrapButton.java:108)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:288)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:607)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:743)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:806)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:809)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:504)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:414)
        at com.app.view.PreShareFragment.onCreateView(PreShareFragment.java:81)
        at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:1504)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:942)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1121)
        at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:682)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1484)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onStart(FragmentActivity.java:571)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnStart(Instrumentation.java:1220)
        at android.app.Activity.performStart(Activity.java:5949)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2261)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2360)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:144)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1278)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)
```

Comment: The error is exactly what is says it is. BootstrapButton is trying to make calls to recycled instance of TypedArray. Use a different library or ask the author to fix it.

Comment: That's right, I finally figured that out about an hour ago.  The fix is in the answer below.

Answer (score 2):

The solution is to move the lines:

```
        if (a.getString(R.styleable.BootstrapButton_android_textSize) == null) {
            fontSize = bootstrapSize.getFontSize();
        }
```

before the "finally" block which recycles the a variable:

```
 finally {
        a.recycle();
    }
```

the final BootstrapButton.java file is [here](http://pastebin.com/e5uHUvs3)

Answer (score 1):

Newer versions of AndroidBootstrap will throw this error if you don't add `TypefaceProvider.registerDefaultIconSets()` in your Application init(), as said in the [docs](https://github.com/Bearded-Hen/Android-Bootstrap):

> You should also override your application class with the following:

```
public class SampleApplication extends Application {
     @Override public void onCreate() {
         super.onCreate();
         TypefaceProvider.registerDefaultIconSets();
     }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Solve it !

Since December 3rd, 2014, build tools 1.0.0-rc1 was released. Now, all you need to do is:

1) Modify your Main Project  build.gradle file like so:

```
android {
compileSdkVersion 22
buildToolsVersion "23.0.0"

     defaultConfig {
         minSdkVersion 14 //lower than 14 doesn't support multidex
         targetSdkVersion 22

         // Enabling multidex support.
         multiDexEnabled true
     }


dependencies {
compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
}
```

2) Also you must change your manifest file from your main project.

```
 <application
    ...
    android:name="android.support.multidex.MultiDexApplication">
    ...

    </application >
```

3) If you want more information please consult those sources

https://developer.android.com/tools/building/multidex.html
http://blog.osom.info/2014/10/multi-dex-to-rescue-from-infamous-65536.html